# How to use multiple Scriptmanagers in a page asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a dialog box where user sign up and login are there both are in the asp.net ajax(Script manager) . I used asp.net field validations for all inputs. When i tried to login it also asking to enter inputs for signup form too. How make those two things separate and make use of asp.net ajax. Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated. 
TIA

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="sidebar js-sidebar-aside">
            <div class="sidebar__wrapper">
                <div class="sidebar__close js-toggle-sidebar visible-xs">
                    <span class="oi oi-x"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar__form form_alt">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__username">
                            Username</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" ID="txtUserName" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="reqName"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__password">
                            Password</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="password" class="form-control" runat="server" ID="txtPassword"
                            placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password!" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                        ID="btnSignIn" Text="Sign In" OnClick="btnSignIn_Click"></asp:Button>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="sidebar__heading" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <h4 class="sidebar__heading">
                    Didn't invite anyone?
                </h4>
                <ul class="sidebar__menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="sidebar__form form_alt">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__username">
                            Email</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" ID="txtSignUpEmail"
                            placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpEmail" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Emial!" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Email ID"
                            ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpEmail" CssClass="sidebar__heading"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__username">
                            Username</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" ID="txtSignUpUserName"
                            placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpUserName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Username!" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__password">
                            Password</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="password" runat="server" class="form-control" ID="txtSignUpPassword"
                            placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpPassword" ErrorMessage="Please enter your password!" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExp1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password length must be between 7 to 10 characters"
                            ControlToValidate="txtSignUpPassword" CssClass="sidebar__heading" Display="Dynamic"
                            ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{7,10}$" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__password">
                            Repeat Password</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="password" runat="server" class="form-control" ID="txtSignUpRepeatPassword"
                            placeholder="Repeat Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpRepeatPassword" ErrorMessage="Please enter your RepeatPassword!" />
                        <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="Comp1" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpPassword"
                            CssClass="sidebar__heading" Display="Dynamic" ControlToCompare="txtSignUpRepeatPassword"
                            Text="Password mismatch" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" Text="Sign UP"
                        OnClick="btnSignup_Click"></asp:Button>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="sidebar__heading" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: can you add your code here so that we can get an idea of what you tried and the place you got stucked.

Comment: Adding code...... please have a look give your comments

Comment: do you have issue with _validations_ here which both are firing at the same time ?

Comment: Yes. when i am logging in then the signup validators also firing forcing me to enter the sign up form. Which is wrong

Comment: check, I have posted the answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be facing the issue because you haven't set the `ValidationGroup` to both the buttons.

Here you go

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="sidebar js-sidebar-aside">
            <div class="sidebar__wrapper">
                <div class="sidebar__close js-toggle-sidebar visible-xs">
                    <span class="oi oi-x"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar__form form_alt">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__username">
                            Username</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" ID="txtUserName" placeholder="Username"
                            ValidationGroup="SignIn"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="reqName"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" ValidationGroup="SignIn" ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__password">
                            Password</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="password" ValidationGroup="SignIn" class="form-control" runat="server"
                            ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="SignIn" runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading"
                            ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter Password!" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" type="submit" ValidationGroup="SignIn" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"
                        UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="btnSignIn" Text="Sign In" OnClick="btnSignIn_Click">
                    </asp:Button>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="sidebar__heading" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <h4 class="sidebar__heading">
                    Didn't invite anyone?
                </h4>
                <ul class="sidebar__menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="sidebar__form form_alt">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__username">
                            Email</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="text" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" class="form-control"
                            ID="txtSignUpEmail" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading"
                            ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpEmail"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter your Emial!" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Email ID"
                            ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpEmail" CssClass="sidebar__heading"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__username">
                            Username</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="text" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" class="form-control"
                            ID="txtSignUpUserName" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpUserName"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter your Username!" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__password">
                            Password</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="password" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" class="form-control"
                            ID="txtSignUpPassword" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading"
                            ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpPassword"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter your password!" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExp1" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Password length must be between 7 to 10 characters" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpPassword"
                            CssClass="sidebar__heading" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{7,10}$" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="login__password">
                            Repeat Password</label>
                        <asp:TextBox type="password" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" class="form-control"
                            ID="txtSignUpRepeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="sidebar__heading"
                            ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpRepeatPassword"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter your RepeatPassword!" />
                        <asp:CompareValidator ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" runat="server" ID="Comp1" ControlToValidate="txtSignUpPassword"
                            CssClass="sidebar__heading" Display="Dynamic" ControlToCompare="txtSignUpRepeatPassword"
                            Text="Password mismatch" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" Text="Sign UP"
                        OnClick="btnSignup_Click" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit"></asp:Button>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="sidebar__heading" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```